# localstorage to store and retrieve non-blank ID

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a loop that uses localstorage to store non-blank ID #M1 to #M48 
But also need a method to retrieve the localstorage vars. I suspect the answer has something to do with JSON.stringify.

How can I do this?

```
<form>

<input type = "text" id = "M1" />
<input type = "text" id = "M2" />
<input type = "text" id = "M3" />
...

</form>

<script> //store the variables

$max_entrants = 48;     

for ($i = 0; $i <= $max_entrants; $i++) {

localStorage.setItem("LS-MEM_" +$i, "M" +$i);

}

</script>

<script> //retrieve the variables into a form using ID#s

$max_entrants = 48;     

for ($i = 0; $i <= $max_entrants; $i++) {

$wrench = localStorage.getItem("LS-MEM_" +$i); 
$("#M" +$i).val($wrench); 

}

</script>
```

The script just above this was tested and failed.

```
<div id = "result"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("LS-MEM_2");
</script>
```

Output was ======>> "M2"

Can this be fixed?

Comment: I think you'll also want to get the value from the textbox. Do some research around `getElementById`.

Comment: can the answer be added and marked as such?

Comment: Yes. I suspect the answer has something to do with JSON.stringify. If you post an answer that works, I'll mark it as helpful and as a solution.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to just make array from your values, stringify it and just save it to one localstore key. you could then just get all values from one key and build logic around whole array object.

Comment: and could you please re-produce this in jsfiddle example

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Your code sample just stores key / value pairs like `LS_MEM_1: 'M1'` so the output that you want to "fix" is expected. What output are you hoping for?

Comment: Your code works fine. What else did you expect? It correctly stores the values in local storage, gets them, and assign them to respective textboxes. See a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/592497/).

Comment: I was hoping to store integers, dollar amounts. Then when I go to another page, and then return, I could onblur the input field and the stored value would be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the string „M2“ is what you stored in the local storage. Try something like this (assuming u use jQuery) for storing the values.

```
localStorage.setItem("LS-MEM_" +$i, $jQuery("#M"+$i).val() );
```

Link to a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iPirat/26tjsva1/

Comment: document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("LS-MEM_2"); Can you fix this to use the counter instead of the literal LS-MEM_2, please?

Comment: I give up. No answer is forthcoming.

Comment: the answer is here. replacing the `"LS-MEM_2"` by `"LS-MEM_" + $i` is a trivial excercise

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle to also read all three values from local storage to spans. hope that helps

Comment: PS. and also replaced `getElementById` by its jQuery equivalent